# Cascading dropdown in Kendo grid returns null when bound to nullable field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that contains two sets of cascading dropdowns: One for Locations level 1 to 3, and another for Category level 1 to 3. In my model the Locations are all not nullable, while for Category level 2 and level 3 are nullable.

I use inline editing, and all combos are populating correctly. When I save, however, the nullable comboboxes's selected values are not included in the post, and the ActionResult receives a null value for these two fields of the model.

The grid:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Container>()
              .Name("ContainerGrid")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(150);                 
                  columns.ForeignKey(c => c.LocationLevel1Id, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["locationLevel1"], "Id", "Text").EditorTemplateName("LocationLevel1Id");
                  columns.ForeignKey(c => c.LocationLevel2Id, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["locationLevel2"], "Id", "Text").EditorTemplateName("LocationLevel2Id");
                  columns.ForeignKey(c => c.LocationLevel3Id, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["locationLevel3"], "Id", "Text").EditorTemplateName("LocationLevel3Id");
                  columns.ForeignKey(c => c.CategoryLevel1Id, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["catLevel1"], "Id", "Text").EditorTemplateName("CategoryLevel1Id");
                  columns.ForeignKey(c => c.CategoryLevel2Id, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["catLevel2"], "Id", "Text").EditorTemplateName("CategoryLevel2Id");
                  columns.ForeignKey(c => c.CategoryLevel3Id, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["catLevel3"], "Id", "Text").EditorTemplateName("CategoryLevel3Id");
              })
                 .ColumnMenu()
                .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))             
                .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .PageSize(100)
                    .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(a => a.Id);                      
                        model.Field(a => a.LocationLevel1Id);
                        model.Field(a => a.LocationLevel2Id);
                        model.Field(a => a.LocationLevel3Id);                      
                        model.Field(a => a.CategoryLevel1Id);
                        model.Field(a => a.CategoryLevel2Id);
                        model.Field(a => a.CategoryLevel3Id);
                    })
                    .Read(read => read.Action("Containers_Read", "ContainerAdmin").Data("filterInfo").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
                    .Create(update => update.Action("Containers_Create", "ContainerAdmin"))
                    .Update(update => update.Action("Containers_Update", "ContainerAdmin"))
                )

        )
```

and the Model:

```
public class Container
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LocationLevel1")]
        public Guid LocationLevel1Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "locationLevel1")]
        public virtual Location LocationLevel1 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LocationLevel2")]
        public Guid LocationLevel2Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "locationLevel2")]
        public virtual Location LocationLevel2 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LocationLevel3")]
        public Guid LocationLevel3Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "locationLevel3")]
        public virtual Location LocationLevel3 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CategoryLevel1")]
        public Guid? CategoryLevel1Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "categoryLevel1")]
        public virtual Category CategoryLevel1 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CategoryLevel2")]
        public Guid? CategoryLevel2Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "categoryLevel2")]
        public virtual Category CategoryLevel2 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CategoryLevel3")]
        public Guid? CategoryLevel3Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "categoryLevel3")]
        public virtual Category CategoryLevel3 { get; set; }

    }
```

How can I get the Category level 2 and level 3 values to the ActionResult **WITHOUT** changing these fields to not-nullable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much searching, I found the answer at http://www.sitereq.com/post/kendo-mvc-dropdown-lists-inside-inline-kendo-mvc-grids

> **Take care of the nullable model properties**
>     This is an important note to take care of. In case your model consists of nullable
>   properties of integer, floats or even byte types, the Kendo grid will
>   not be able to update the model properties to their values on create
>   or edit events. It's a known bug in Kendo grids having Kendo drop down
>   lists in their editor template. So in case the CompanyId is
>   Nullable instead of int then to work around this you have to add
>   the "save" event to the grid like in the following listing
>
> ```
> .Events(events =>
>     {
>         events.Save("EmployeesGrid_Save");
>     })
> ```
>
> where EmployeesGrid_Save is the javascript handler that will handle
>   the grid save event. The following listing describe how the save
>   handler will help the grid to save the values of the drop down lists
>   to their corresponding nullable properties.
>
> ```
> function EmployeesGrid_Save(e) {
>         var companyId = $("#CompanyId").data().kendoDropDownList.value();
>         e.model.set("CompanyId", companyId);
>     }
> ```

I implemented this, and it works!